# Back layer of two svg doesn't receive click event

Tags: html, css, click, event-propagation

I try to create many svg in HTML that overlays each over. I want to handle click events on each layer of svg images. Is it possible?

```css
svg {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" onCLick="console.log('1')">
    <circle r="100" cx="100" cy="100" fill="#CCCCCC"></circle>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" onCLick="console.log('2')">
    <circle r="100" cx="200" cy="200" fill="#DDDDDD"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

It would be easier to look on demonstration https://jsfiddle.net/etmy35y3/ 
I want to receive a click events on both svg elements and write both 1 and 2 on console.

How to receive events on both elements?

My problem is about multiple `svg` elements on HTML page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I map click events to elements in multiple layers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252207/how-can-i-map-click-events-to-elements-in-multiple-layers)

Comment: Probably not because my problem is for multiple `svg` elements. However I will check your link