# Invoke click events on two superimposed, non-hierarchical elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

Elements A and B are not parent and child.
Element A is layered (transparently) over the top of Element B.
Element B has a button on it.

I want clicking on the button to trigger click events on both A and B.

If B were a child of A (or vice-versa) this would happen automatically (HTML event bubbling JustWorks like that), and `event.stopPropagation()` would allow me to prevent this if I needed to.

If I wanted the click to pass through the top-most layer (A) and invoke the button on B, then I would use `pointer-events:none` but that means that NO event is triggered on A.

Can this be achieved?
See JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7mhb5e7c/ I want both events to be fired from a single click.

(For reference, this is not directly my problem, merely my current favourite design for the fix. My actual problem is [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853296/make-menu-dissappear-on-clickoff-on-tablet).
If you have a better solution that solves the real problem feel free to comment over there. But I'd like to know whether this design is **possible** for general knowledge, even if it's not the best fix)

Comment: Feed  us with some code, will helpful to solve your issue.

Comment: I don't think it's the best approach, if both layers have interactive elements, they shouldnt be overlapped, better use tabs or something. That doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: You could use something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3735306/1469259

Comment: @DaseinA I agree I don't think it's ideal, so if you have a better solution to my actual problem (now linked) I'd be very grateful indeed.

Comment: I told you: use tabs or something different. Overlapping the elements will get you stuck for any good reason.

Comment: @DaseinA "Use tabs" or "do it differently" aren't solutions to my problem. Have you looked at the details of the problem that I linked to?

Comment: @DaseinA and you. All the best.

Comment: What if you called a function on click, passed mouse position as param and then iterated through all your buttons doing collision tests..?

Comment: @Zze Ugh .. that would be horrible. However it seems kinda like that's the only way it could be done given the lack of better answers. Sad times.

Comment: Very sad times... Not sure how else you would do it though unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.filter-layer').on('click',function(e) { 
    alert('filter clicked'); 
});
$('button').on('click',function(e) { 
    $('.filter-layer').trigger('click');
    alert('button clicked'); 
});
```

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/7mhb5e7c/1/)

Comment: I agree that this works for that one scenario, but  for my actual purpose (put a transparent layer over the entire page) it's not feasible as that line would be required everywhere.